# How to have many tables displays in a view from one database?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I have a product database table with these fields:

Name
Category (e.g product type)
Subcategory (e.g packaging)
Price

E.g category A has 3 kinds of packaging. I would like it to display in three different tables in view. I can get the three tables out seperately but the tables are showing the same data.

Could someone help me pls?

I have this codes in my public ViewResult Index() controllers class.
var productsCornIndustrial = from cornIndustrial in db.Products
                                         where cornIndustrial.Category == "Corn Oil" & cornIndustrial.SubCategory == "Industrial"
                                         select cornIndustrial;

```
        return View(productsCornIndustrial.ToList());

        var productsCornFoodservice = from cornFoodservice in db.Products
                                      where cornFoodservice.Category == "Corn Oil" & cornFoodservice.SubCategory == "Foodservice"
                                      select cornFoodservice;

        return View(productsCornFoodservice.ToList());

        var productsCornRetail = from cornRetail in db.Products
                                 where cornRetail.Category == "Corn Oil" & cornRetail.SubCategory == "Retail"
                                 select cornRetail;

        return View(productsCornRetail.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about ViewModels pattern. I would write it like this :

Build a separate ViewModel class that will hold all your data :

```
public class NewViewModel
{
  public List<Products> IndustrialList {get;set;}
  public List<Products> FoodList {get;set;}
  public List<Products> RetailList{get;set;}

  //ctor etc... get the data from DAL
}
```

....

and use this class in your controller to pass tot the view a strong-typed ViewModel object:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
  var items = new NewViewModel();
  return View(items);
}
```

Comment: Well, I am creating for a web app 3 projects in the same solution. 1) Core - Class Library where i have DAL code and repository 2) UI - the MVC app 3)Unit Tests. So you could add all your code in a separate assebly and structure it there, and in your controller just add the assembly